Can you automatically break authors into multiple lines in the IEEE conference template?
Within a latex document, if there are a lot of authors or authors with long names, the IEEEauthorblockN will not break automatically, but become very long, as shown by the following mre:
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\title{Many Authors}

\author{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{
        Mickey Mouse,
        Goofy,
        Donald Duck,
        Daisy Duck,
        Huey Duck,
        Dewey Duck,
        Louie Duck,
        Gyro Gearloose,
        Scrooge McDuck
    }
}
\maketitle
\end{document}


Do I have to manually insert a line break or can I instruct latex to break the authors section so it fits on the page?

You would never guess from the documentation but it is really a tabular and it seems you are supposed to add \\  by hand after the comma to force line breaks.

Welcome to TeX.SE.
